# how to find htaccess file in filezilla

Tags: web, hosting, web-hosting

i am looking for .htaccess in `Filezilla`. But evan after clicking `Force showing hidden file` in the `Server` menu. But .htaccess file is still not visible.Any idea?

My website is in asp.net if this make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have a .haccess file in you server.

So, you have to create a htaccess.txt, upload it in your filezilla and rename it .htaccess

Hope this helps you